# How to return the observable from promise

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to get the bearer token from storage using `@Ionic/storage`.
The Ionic storage returns a promise.
Then I need to use this with `angular http` request which will return Observable.

How can I achieve the same? Or is it possible that I can have a pure return type as Observable with `@Ionic/Storage`?

```
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    let promise = this.requestOptions(options).then((options) => {
      return super.get(this.getFullUrl(url), options)
        .catch(this.onCatch)
        .do((res: Response) => {
          this.onSubscribeSuccess(res);
        }, (error: any) => {
          this.onSubscribeError(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.onFinally();
        });
    });
    return Observable.fromPromise(promise);
  }
```

RequestOptions function:

```
 private requestOptions(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Promise<RequestOptionsArgs> {
    if (options == null) {
      options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (options.headers == null) {
      return this.currentUser.currentToken().then((token) => {
        options.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        return this.currentUser.getAppVersion().then((version: string) => {
          options.headers.append("appVersion", version);
          return options;
        })
      })
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I dont understand why is the answer part of the question. Also 2 pieces of advice. Use async/await to make the code look cleaner and cache the token and don't request it via promise everytime you try to use it.

Comment: Can you please provide some example. I will be using this for the native app.

Comment: check this line `return super.get(this.getFullUrl(url), options)`  i think the parameters are not wright